# How to interpret html in an attribute with Vue

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to convert some code to Vue, I have a rendering difference in the `alt` attribute of an image, because I can't find a way to interpret the html in the attributes, I haven't found any topics that talk about this do you have an idea please?

In the examples I made on purpose not to put `src` to see the alternative texts.

```js
Vue.component('first-image', {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  template: '<div class="container-image"><img v-bind="$attrs"></div>'
});

Vue.component('second-image', {
  template: '<img>',
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
       alternativeText: '1&nbsp;000€',
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Without VueJS -->
<img alt="1&nbsp;000€">

<br>
<br>

<!-- With VueJS -->
<div id="app">
  <first-image :alt="alternativeText"></first-image>
  <second-image alt="1&nbsp;000€"></second-image>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like following snippet:

```js
Vue.component('first-image', {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  template: '<div class="container-image"><img v-bind="$attrs"></div>'
});

Vue.component('second-image', {
  template: '<img>',
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
       alternativeText: '1&nbsp;000€',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    decodeHtml(html) {
      const txt = document.createElement("textarea");
      txt.innerHTML = html;
      return txt.value;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<!-- Without VueJS -->
<img alt="1&nbsp;000€">

<br>
<br>

<!-- With VueJS -->
<div id="app">
  <first-image :alt="decodeHtml(alternativeText)"></first-image>
  <second-image alt="1&nbsp;000€"></second-image>
</div>
```